# Propper heater hose routing

Tags: chevrolet, hose, equinox, heater-core

2008 Chevrolet Equinox with the 3.4 and the heater hoses were taken off. I am trying to hook up my heater hoses to the heater core at the firewall in the engine compartment. Somebody took them off and I do not want to hook them up backwards and I would appreciate any help with this issue. Does anyone have a diagram or something that would help me understand what I need to do.

Comment: I have found that if you search for a part then switch to image results you often get an image of the part, along with surround parts showing where they all fit.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!